# Different boost values for different indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

Using ElasticSearch, I run queries across several indexes. But I want the results coming from different indexes to have different weights (~ different "boost factor" in ES parlance, I think).

The goal is to tweak the ranking of query results, on a per-index **and** per-query basis. I want a soft preference of results from chosen indexes, not a hard yes/no filter on indexes.

Example:

```
Query results, 3 hits:

1. doc A, from index Z, score 0.7
2. doc B, from index Y, score 0.6
3. doc C, from index Y, score 0.65
```

I want to boost all results from index Y (docs B and C) so they get a higher score. Different queries require different index weights. How do I do that in the query DSL syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, found out that ES supports that out of the box:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/index-boost.html